# Interfaces, generics and implicit operations

Tags: c#, generics, interface, implicit-conversion

Suppose I have these types:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(T value)
    {
         Value = value;
    }

    public T Value {get;set;}

    public static implicit operator Foo<T>(T t)
    {
        return new Foo<T>(t);
    }
}

public interface IBar
{
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
}
```

Why am I not allowed to write this?

```
Foo<IBar> foo = (IBar)new Bar();
```

But still allowed to write this?

```
Foo<Bar> foo = new Bar();
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type IBar to Foo< IBar >. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I know I can't use implicit operators with interfaces, but why I can't use them when interface is a generic argument?

Comment: Casting from interface is a build-in conversion. You can not override build-in conversions.

Comment: It works without `(IBar)`.

Comment: Personally I would avoid doing this anyway - it's *really* confusing code. Why not add an extension method instead? `public static Foo<T> ToFoo<T>(this T t)`?

Comment: I was thinking to develop my own class to replace System.Lazy which is a bit annoying to convert back and forth to a value. So I added couple implicit operators for converting from and to my own lazy class. Everything worked perfectly until I tried to use interface as a generic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the generic parameters and just have `operator Foo(IBar t)`, it raises [CS0552](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/as5zfadk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> You cannot create a user-defined conversion to or from an interface. If you need the conversion routine, resolve this error by making the interface a class or derive a class from the interface.

So user defined conversions between interfaces aren't allowed. It's related to the first error you got:

> Cannot implicitly convert type IBar to Foo< IBar >. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If there is already an explicit conversion (now from *IBar* to *Foo*), there can't be an implicit one.

So you can't overload user-defined conversion from or to interfaces because there is already a build-in conversion defined for the type (albeit an explicit one).

Comment: I understand I cannot implicitly cast an interface, but generic class is still a class even if generic argument is an interface.

Comment: @xBodro It is, but `(IBar)new Bar()` is an interface, which you can't cast using a user-defined operator.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about what I am going to say.
Isn't that because it won't accept something casted to interface(because there can't be created an object from a class) , but will accept everything that is implementing the interface.